# Vector Fields in Manim

Tags: python, manim

Can anyone please explain the concept behind the ‘func’ argument when creating a vector field in Manim? For instance:

```
func = lambda p: np.sin(p[0] / 2) * UR + np.cos(p[1] / 2) * LEFT
```

I’m only familiar with the `lambda p: np.array([])` method. What’s the significance of the unit steps (`UR`, `UP`, `UL`, etc..) and when to use them correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The interface is, unfortunately, a bit clumsy. A vector field visualizes a function mapping a vector to another vector; this is what the specified function models.

The examples on the [corresponding page in the documentation](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/reference/manim.mobject.vector_field.ArrowVectorField.html#arrowvectorfield) pass the vector function as a lambda function which maps a numpy vector `p` with three components (think of it as a list `[x, y, z]`) to its corresponding image. Manim's unit step constants `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, `UR`, etc. are just vectors `np.array([-1, 0, 0])`, `np.array([1, 0, 0])`, `np.array([1, 1, 0])` that can help to describe the right-hand side of the function a little easier.

Take, as an example, the function f(x, y) = (-y, x). As a lambda-function in the same style of the documentation you could write that as `lambda p: p[1]*LEFT + p[0]*UP` -- or, alternatively, as `lambda p: np.array(-p[1], p[0], 0)`. (Just make sure that you return a vector with three components.)